# Unnormalized result of Word Mover's Distance with SpaCy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm trying to use Fast Word Mover's Distance library with SpaCy, for the same example in the [GitHub](https://github.com/src-d/wmd-relax)

```
import spacy
import wmd
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
nlp.add_pipe(wmd.WMD.SpacySimilarityHook(nlp), last=True)

doc1 = nlp("Politician speaks to the media in Illinois.")
doc2 = nlp("The president greets the press in Chicago.")
print(doc1.similarity(doc2))
```

The result is:

```
6.070106029510498
```

I don't know how to interpret it, since usually distance is normalized (0 to 1). In the readme file, the result for this is not available, hence I'm not sure if my result is wrong or the scale for this measurement is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A short answer: **don't interpret it**. Use it just like this: the lower is the distance, the more similar are sentences. For virtually all practical applications (e.g. KNN) this is enough.

Now the long answer: word mover distance (read [the paper](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~kilian/papers/wmd_metric.pdf)) is defined as the weighted average of distances between best matching pairs of "non-stop" words. So if you want to normalize it into (0, 1), you need to divide this best sum by its worst case.

The problem is that in `spacy` word vectors are not normalized (check it by printing `[sum(t.vector**2) for t in doc1]`). Therefore, the maximal distance between them is unlimited. And if you do normalize them, the new WMD will not be equivalent to original WMD (i.e. it will sort pairs of texts differently). Therefore, there is no obvious way to normalize the original spacy-WMD distances that you demonstrated.

Now let's pretend that word vectors are unit-normalized. If it is the case, then the maximal distance between two words is the diameter of a unit sphere (that is, 2). And the maximal weighted average of many 2s is still 2. So you need to divide the distance between texts by 2 to make it fully normalized.

You can build word vector normalization into WMD calculation by inheriting the class you use:

```
import wmd
import numpy
import libwmdrelax

class NormalizedWMDHook(wmd.WMD.SpacySimilarityHook):
    def compute_similarity(self, doc1, doc2):
        """
        Calculates the similarity between two spaCy documents. Extracts the
        nBOW from them and evaluates the WMD.

        :return: The calculated similarity.
        :rtype: float.
        """
        doc1 = self._convert_document(doc1)
        doc2 = self._convert_document(doc2)
        vocabulary = {
            w: i for i, w in enumerate(sorted(set(doc1).union(doc2)))}
        w1 = self._generate_weights(doc1, vocabulary)
        w2 = self._generate_weights(doc2, vocabulary)
        evec = numpy.zeros((len(vocabulary), self.nlp.vocab.vectors_length),
                           dtype=numpy.float32)
        for w, i in vocabulary.items():
            v = self.nlp.vocab[w].vector                                      # MODIFIED
            evec[i] = v / (sum(v**2)**0.5)                                    # MODIFIED
        evec_sqr = (evec * evec).sum(axis=1)
        dists = evec_sqr - 2 * evec.dot(evec.T) + evec_sqr[:, numpy.newaxis]
        dists[dists < 0] = 0
        dists = numpy.sqrt(dists)
        return libwmdrelax.emd(w1, w2, dists) / 2                             # MODIFIED
```

Now you can be sure that your distance is properly normalized:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
nlp.add_pipe(NormalizedWMDHook(nlp), last=True)
doc1 = nlp("Politician speaks to the media in Illinois.")
doc2 = nlp("The president greets the press in Chicago.")
print(doc1.similarity(doc2))
print(doc1.similarity(doc1))
print(doc1.similarity(nlp("President speaks to the media in Illinois.")))
print(doc1.similarity(nlp("some irrelevant bullshit")))
print(doc1.similarity(nlp("JDL")))
```

Now the result is

```
0.469503253698349
0.0
0.12690649926662445
0.6037049889564514
0.7507566213607788
```

P.S. You can see that even between two very unrelated texts this normalized distance is much less than 1. This is because in reality word vectors don't cover the whole unit sphere  - instead, most of them are clustered on several "continents" on it. Therefore, the distance even between very different texts would be typically less than 1.